# What will be the standing of teams in a situation, where 3 teams have equal points and tournament rules don't specify tie-breakers between 3 teams?

Tags: football, tie-breaker

A league of 8 teams playing with each other 2 times, 3 teams have equal points.

```
A vs B:   2-0, 2-1  
C vs A:   2-0, 2-1
B vs C:   6-2, 1-2
```

Goal difference:

```
A -2
B -1
C -12
```

*Which team is above A, B or C?*

**Tie-breaker rules:**

1. Point obtained
2. Direct confrontation between 2 tying team
3. Superior goal difference

Comment: What do the rules say when there are more than 2 tied teams?

Comment: Nothing it's as I mentioned above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Assuming that your example is correct and the tournament rules don't mention any further details...*

If those three teams all have the same amount of points and the results are correct we can safely use the "direct confrontation" you've mentioned. In the real world it is usually a small table using only the results between those teams that are tied for points, in this case our three teams.

This means

- Team A has 2 wins, 2 losses
- Team B has 1 win, 3 losses
- Team C has 3 wins, 1 loss

This results in the following mini table:

```
Rank Team  Pts  Goals  GD
 1.    C    9    8-8    0
 2.    A    6    5-5    0
 3.    B    3    8-8    0
```

So in the final table the order is C > A > B and the goal difference doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: Why points are again calculated here? Its already calculated in the main league. My view is we must look add the direct confrontation . Each team won the confrontation here. Each team won 1 confrontation.  So must look at goal difference

Comment: @Roy, usually when 3 or more teams are tied, the points (and then goal differences) obtained in the matches played exclusively between the teams in question are taken into account. Besides that it's a league tournament not knock-out series, so thinking of 2 games played between 2 particular teams as pairings of a knock-out tournament is very unusual.

Comment: @RoySokoo it's like gdrt said and I already mentioned: the direct confrontation between more than two teams are *all* games between them and the points and goals will be calculated in an extra table. A direct confrontation does not just count who beat who. You also have to calculate the scores again. And since team C won 3 of their games they're the winner here.

Comment: @edit it's not code, it's a <pre> block

Comment: Thank You very much guys. However one thing is not clear here. Points obtained?  By the teams concerned among them or in the whole league it hasn't mentioned here.

Comment: @RoySokoo "*table using only the results between those teams*" already refers to that. Only the matches between the teams that are tied count. The points of the whole league were already taken into account in the primary table and are the reason why the teams are tied.

Comment: That mean the rule is not clear here. It must has been highest points obtained 'among the teams concerned'

Comment: As a real life example I will add link to [Group F in 2013-14 Champions League](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2013–14_UEFA_Champions_League_group_stage#Group_F). Of course, in that case it was clearly stated in the rules that ties are resolved this way - I am posting this merely as an example that something like this indeed happens and that the criteria described in the answer are commonly used.