# Soccer Standings

Tags: football

consider a league of 10 teams
Each play each other two time
No Home/Away

3 team, A, B & C have same number of points

A vs B  2 - 0 2 - 1
B vs C 2- 1  2 - 0
C vs A  6 - 2  1 -2

Rules apply

Rule 1

if two teams or more, end the championship with the same number of points the following shall
apply in the order of priority as given below:
a) Higher number of points.
b. Direct confrontation between two tying teams
C.superior g.differerence between the team in question.

Rule 2
if two teams or more, end the championship with the same number of points the following shall
apply in the order of priority as given below:
a) Higher number of points obtained in matches among the team in questions.
b. Same as rule 1b
C. Same as rule 1c

what is the difference between these two rules and the standing in each case???

Answer (score 1):

Just like already mentioned in your [other question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/18080/what-will-be-the-standing-of-teams-in-a-situation-where-3-teams-have-equal-poin) there is **no difference**.

**Let's use two teams first...**

Now for example A and B are tied for points and played 1-1 and 0-3:

1. direct confrontation:

   - A has a draw and loss = 1 point and 1-4 goals
   - B has a draw and win = 4 points and 4-1 goals
   - B wins
2. Points to win:

   - A still has 1 point and 1-4 goals
   - B still has 4 points and 4-1 goals
   - B wins

**With 3 teams:**

In both cases the winner of the tie will be the one with the most points.
If you want to compare more than two team's results for the direct confrontation rule it is necessary to add up all results between the tied teams. It does not work to just compare A with B and B with C and A with C. Yes, they would have won one duel each, but the **results** count, **not the comparisons**.

You try to do this:

- A wins against B -> 1 for A
- B wins against C -> 1 for B
- C wins against A -> 1 for C

While that is technically true you would ignore the actual results, which is all the league table is about. Even in direct confrontation only the results matter.

So you have to accumulate all results:

A played against B and C -> take all matches against B and C into account. A won 3 out of 4 matches against B *and* C. That is what matters.

Do the same for the other teams and you can create a table from the results:

- A won both matches against B and one against C = 3 wins = 9 points
- B won both matches against C = 2 wins = 6 points
- C won only one match against A = 1 win = 3 points